# XAML parsing exception compiling Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, windows-phone-8, appbar

I'm trying to compile a Windows Phone 8 project on Visual Studio IDE 2013 and I get an error with the parsing of the **MainPage.xaml**.

In the following code I get the error `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException`.
What I wrong? The issue is originated in the line of the opening `AppBar` tag.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MainStream.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MainStream"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="None" Source="/img/sfondo.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="480" Height="270" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Image Width="480" Height="270" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20"/>
        </FlipView>

        <AppBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AppBarButton Click="Play_Click" Label="Play" Icon="Play"/>
                <AppBarButton Click="Pause_Click" Label="Pause" Icon="Pause"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </AppBar>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The error is:

> Cannot create instance of type '%0' [Line: 18 Position: 17]
>   The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Anyone can suggest me a solution?

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think the AppBar has to be a child of the Page element. I.e it shouldn't be within the <Grid> Element, it should be before or after it.

Comment: Are you coding for WP8 or WP8.1 by the way, as I'm sure thats not the correct xaml for an application bar in WP8

Comment: Thank you, but from the Microsoft documentation I'm not still understand what is the correct form.

Comment: I'll repeat are you using Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone 8.1? 8.1 has a different xaml style for its action bar than Windows Phone 8 and most of the answers below are for a Windows Phone 8.1 style application

Comment: You are a Genius! I'm solved. I'm remove the '<AppBar> </AppBar>' tag, probably, as you said, it wasn't a child of the <Grid> Element. Just remove it, and it Works! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I have added an answer below that summarise what I was saying. If you could accept it as the answer that would be great.

Comment: Well done! I didn't know how to give you points for thank you. Good continuation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that the appbar should be a child of the grid element and I am not sure that you are using the correct format for a appbar. The correct way would be something similar to below:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MainStream.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MainStream"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="None" Source="/img/sfondo.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="480" Height="270" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Image Width="480" Height="270" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20"/>
        </FlipView>
   </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Opacity="1">
            <AppBarButton x:Name="AddAppBarButton" Label="add" Icon="Add"  />
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton x:Uid="SecondaryButton1" x:Name="SecondaryButton1" Label="secondary command 1" />
                <AppBarButton x:Uid="SecondaryButton2" x:Name="SecondaryButton2" Label="secondary command 2" />
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Page x:Class="MainStream.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:MainStream"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Page.BottomAppBar>
          <AppBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
           <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AppBarButton Click="Play_Click" Label="Play" Icon="Play"/>
                <AppBarButton Click="Pause_Click" Label="Pause" Icon="Pause"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="None" Source="/img/sfondo.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="480" Height="270" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <Image Width="480" Height="270" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#CCFFFFFF" Padding="15,20"/>
            </FlipView>    
        </Grid>
         </AppBar>
       </Page.BottomAppBar> 

</Page>
```

modify your helper class.

From

```
App myApp = new App();
```

to

//Following is the right way to access the properties from the App.xaml page.

```
App thisApp = (App)System.Windows.Application.Current;
```

Comment: I have 2 Markup Error: on AppBar and Grid. Any suggestion?

Comment: With your code? He says that the "content" property is set more than once. You know what does it means?

Comment: The error is the same but not the line: Cannot create instance of type '%0' [Line: 11 Position: 17]

Comment: I'm not find **App myApp = new App();** in **App.xaml**. It's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing whatever you want within this piece of code, it could be either `Page.TopAppBar` or `Page.BottomAppBar`.

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
<AppBar>
    <!-- AppBar content -->
</AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Try referring this for more:

[adding app bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781232.aspx)

Comment: In this case, I have 3 Markup Error. It's possible that page.TopAppBar is not compatible with windows phone 8?